# How to exclude some values in sorting with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
id products_name sort
1   abc           0 
2   xyz           1
3   pqr           2
4   qwe           0
```

I want to sort records through the `sort` column and in ascending order, but I don't want the rows with 0 at the top in the result set.
The rows having `0` in the `sort` column should be at the bottom of the result set, and the rest of the rows should be sorted in ascending order using the `sort` column.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
ORDER BY IF(SORT=0, 999999999, SORT)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `ORDER BY IF` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY IF(SORT = 0, 999999999, SORT)
```

or you can use the `UNION ALL` statement to achieve this:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE sort > 0 ORDER BY sort)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE sort = 0)
```

Comment: The `UNION` clause implies a sorting that's used to remove duplicates, meaning your output result is not going to be ordered by `sort`. You'll want to use `UNION ALL` to have a chance to evade the sorting pass...

Comment: @Romain : You're right. If you use `UNION`, the results will be filtered from duplicates. Instead, use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: There is no need to `ORDER BY sort` if your WHERE clause is `sort = 0`.